# quotations not bein preserved by echo command when executing from python

Tags: python, bash, sqlite, echo, quotes

In my python script I have the following line -

```
oscmd = "sqlite3 $OMC_DB_DIR/.mcdata \"UPDATE IPADDRESS SET DESCRIPTION = 'NODE0' WHERE HOST LIKE '%-n1.%'\" >/dev/null" .
```

I run this command using subprocess.popen . 
Whenever the command fails, I want to display the failed command on console.

So I do `oscmd_display= "echo \"" + oscmd + "\""` .
I am not just using print but using echo because I want the environment variables like $OMC_DB_DIR to be interpreted and display their actual values.

However, when I run and the command fails, I get message like -

```
[ERROR   ]  Executing the following command failed :
    sqlite3 /opt/store/.mcdata UPDATE IPADDRESS SET DESCRIPTION=NODE0 WHERE HOST LIKE %-n1.% >/dev/null
```

that is, all the quotes stripped off.

I want to preserve both the "" and '' quotes that are in my command.

Could somebody please suggest a solution?

Comment: Add `set -x;` to the start of the command and the shell will show you the line as it runs it. You cannot reliably stick a command in a string and get quoting to work correctly. You can mostly do it for printing but it isn't worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than embedding the entire command line in one string, pass a list containing the command name and the arguments to `subprocess.Popen`.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["sqlite3",
                      # I'm assuming this is an environment variable
                      os.environ['OMC_DB_DIR'] + "/.mcdata",
                      "UPDATE IPADDRESS SET DESCRIPTION = 'NODE0' WHERE HOST LIKE '%-n1.%'",
                      stdout=os.devnull])
```

(If you are using something earlier than Python 2.7, replace `os.devnull` with `open('/dev/null', 'w')`.)

Comment: Can we do it without changing how the subprocess.Popen is being used?

Comment: I wouldn't. Don't structure your code around how you want a log message to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try using triple quotes for the outermost quotes:

```
oscmd = """sqlite3 $OMC_DB_DIR/.mcdata \"UPDATE IPADDRESS SET DESCRIPTION = 'NODE0' WHERE HOST LIKE '%-n1.%'\" >/dev/null"""
```

Comment: doesn't work. No matter what quotes (" ", ' ', " " ") are used in the outer oscmd= ....

Comment: Doesn't work . No matter what quotes (" ", ' ', " " ") are used in the outer oscmd=... command, when it is finally does , oscmd_display= "echo \"" + oscmd + "\""  , the command is interpreted as echo "sqlite3 $OMC_DB_DIR/.mcdata "UPDATE IPADDRESS SET DESCRIPTION ='NODE0' WHERE HOST LIKE '%-n1.%'" >/dev/null"

Answer (score 0):

There are several levels of (de)quoting going on.

In plain SQL, strings must use single quotes:

```sql
SELECT 'some string';
```

In the shell, quotes are used to disable special shell characters, so they must be escaped to end up in the called program:

```sh
sqlite3 filename.db 'SELECT \'some string\';'
```

In Python, you must escape both the backslashes and the quotes so that they are given to the shell:

```py
oscmd = 'sqlite3 filename.db \'SELECT \\\'some string\\\';\'';
```

(How to mix `'` and `"` is left as an exercise …)